# viewing php files in browser?

Tags: php, xampp

So I have just downloaded Xampp to learn php. I've played around making a few simple files and I want to view them in the browser. However I'm not completely sure what url I should be typing into chrome to view the page I want.

**Here's my file set up:**

I have a folder called 'database' saved inside the 'htdocs' folder. Inside the 'database' folder I have a file called 'index.php' that I want to view.

**So what url should I be typing into the broswer to view this page:**

```
localhost/htdocs/database/index.php
```

I think what is confusing me is that I don't know what localhost represents in the url

Comment: try `127.0.0.1/database/index.php` or `localhost/database/index.php` (slower)

Comment: ok so localhost is htdocs

Comment: `localhost/database/` or `127.0.0.1/database/`

Comment: if I put this into an answer, would you upvote me haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of this work for you..

```
localhost/database/ 
127.0.0.1/database/
```

By default, it will look for `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

`htdocs` is your root directory. Type either of these on your browser window to view the file output,

```
http://localhost/database/index.php
http://127.0.0.1/database/index.php
```